# The type or namespace '' does not exist in the class or namespace '' error with Web Reference

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, visual-studio-2012, web-reference

I have a project that is receiving the "The type or namespace '' does not exist in the class or namespace ''" error.  I've seen a lot of solutions here that haven't been able to solve my problem.

The site was downloaded via TFS and I'm using VS 2012.  I've configured the site to run locally through IIS 7.5.  The project build has a target framework of 4.0.

Loading the site in the browser results in your standard 500 - Internal Server Error.  I've checked the Event Viewer and this is the the error along with the stack trace :

> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Jet_Distrib_US\App_Code\CSCode\WM_WebServiceHelper.cs(40):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WM_Get_SoldToRequest' does
>   not exist in the namespace 'WM_JetService' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath
>   virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet
>   excludedSubdirectories)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectories()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod()    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

WM_JetService is set in the Web_References folder of the project.

As an example of one of the errors I am seeing in WM_WebServiceHelper.cs is:

using (WM_JetService.JetServiceSoapClient WMService = new WM_JetService.JetServiceSoapClient())
            {
WM_JetService.**WM_Get_SoldToRequest** request = new WM_JetService.**WM_Get_SoldToRequest**(); ... }

(I'm getting the red error indicators beneath "WM_Get_SoldToRequest").

I can create an instance of WM_JetService but for some reason, I can't reference any of it's methods or properties.

This code works fine for the client locally where it was developed.  I cannot get it to run on my machine locally though.  Also, when I installed VS2012, it updated my framework to 4.5.  Not sure if that has anything to do with this but I've made sure that my AppPool is set to 4.0 and that the project has a targetFramework of 4.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you create a vanilla .NET 4 class library or empty web project, add the web reference to that and try to reference the methods?

Comment: @Greg - Same issue unfortunately.

Comment: If you open the generated code from the web service reference, does anything get underlined or highlighted?  I'm wondering if maybe you need to add an assembly reference.  I encountered something similar a few days ago and it turned out that I needed to add System.Web.Services to my references.

Comment: @Ann - Thanks for the reply.  I did look in the generated code and there doesn't appear to be any errors.  Nothing underlined or highlighted.  I also saw some posts early about adding System.Web.Services to the references.  When I tried that, it already existed so no dice there either.  I also dropped and recreated the web service reference.  This is very confusing to me.

Comment: Can you find `WM_Get_SoldToRequest` in the generated code?  Ah!  Just thought of something.  What namespace was used for the generated code?

Comment: @Ann - I cannot see WM_Get_SoldToRequest in the generated code.  That may be a problem.. however, intellisense isn't picking up ANY of the methods or properties that ARE in the generated code.  "WM_JetService" is the namespace being used.

Comment: Also.. I just setup another site in similar fashion.  Created the site in IIS 7.5.  Connected to the client's TFS.. mapped the TFS site to my local wwwroot directory and pulled down the site via TFS.  Again.. the site won't load because of the same type of error but with a totally different web reference.  Could this be a VS 2012 or IIS 7.5 issue??

Comment: I figured out the cause of this.. kind of.  It runs fine with 4.0 installed but the 4.5 framework is causing this to fail for some reason.  Unfortunately.. I just bought VS 2012 and it requires 4.5 to run.